# Extract URLs from text using Ruby while handling matched parens

Tags: ruby, url, text-processing

[URI.extract](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/URI.html#M004809) claims to do this, but it doesn't handle matched parens:

```
>> URI.extract("text here (http://foo.example.org/bla) and here")
=> ["http://foo.example.org/bla)"]
```

What's the best way to extract URLs from text without breaking parenthesized URLs (which users like to use)?

Comment: Can't you just remove the last ) if it's included?

Comment: I guess, but what if a URL ends in a `)`?

Comment: That's why the ) is being included :)

The parser is assuming it's part of the URL. If you want to pull matching parentheses out, you'll have to handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the URLs are always bound by parentheses a Regular Expression might be a better solution.

```
text = "text here (http://foo.example.org/bla) and here and here is (http://yet.another.url/with/parens) and some more text"
text.scan /\(([^\)]*)\)/
```

Answer (score -1):

Before using this

```
>> URI.extract("text here (http://foo.example.org/bla) and here")
=> ["http://foo.example.org/bla)"]
```

You need to add this

```
require 'uri'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this regexp to extract URL's from  a string

```
"some thing http://abcd.com/ and http://google.com are great".scan(/(?:http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?:(?::[0-9]{1,5})?\/[^\s]*)?/ix)
```

Comment: This has the very same defect. Try matching against "(http://example.com/abc)". This will include the trailing parenthesis.